# What's the deal with two insurance companies in The Postman Always Rings Twice?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-postman-always-rings-twice

In *The Postman Always Rings Twice (1981)* the prosecutor initially relies on an insurance company expert who testifies that Frank was hit with a bottle found on the crash scene and so it was not an accident but a planned crime. The said expert is from the company which issued the Cora's killed husband life insurance policy.

Then Frank's attorney finds a person from another insurance company which issued a health and disability policy and brings them two together. They talk for a while, the second company representative promises his company will pay and the next day the expert from the first company says he made a mistake in his testimony and revokes his previous testimony and the prosecutor has no evidence to rely on now and the trial ends.

What's the deal with two insurance companies that the expert changed his testimony?

Comment: There is no deal between them, just "money talks". For both of them it is cheaper to keep the murder in secret.

Comment: @Voitcus I don't see how it is cheaper for them. Cora is the beneficiary - if she's found guilty then the life insurance remains with the insurance company.

Comment: Well, I don't remember exactly, so I don't post an answer. But AFAIR the "health" one would need to pay Frank's policy. It is said that there is no proof Cora had killed; so to prove it would be a costly process (eg. hire a detective, make lab analyses etc.). So if Frank abandons his insurance, the "health" keeps money. But because "life" has to pay both proving costs and maybe it will get back the money from Cora's policy (they have to pay the money NOW), or maybe not, it is simpler that "health" pays some part of life insurance. This must be cheaper for both of them.

Comment: Maybe this discussion helps: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082934/board/thread/74832613